# Taking the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, when $\epsilon$ is assumed to be positive?

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to look at what will happen to a function $f(x)$ when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. It's previously been assumed that $\epsilon > 0$. Am I then correct in assuming that I only need to consider the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}$?

The function isn't continuous at $\epsilon = 0$, so considering the limit from both sides causes a lot of issues, especially since this discontinuity depends on whether or not $x$ is positive as well. But only considering the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{+}$ allows me to avoid these issues.

It makes sense to me that doing so would be valid, but as I've never encountered this situation before and can't find any answers elsewhere online, I want to verify that my assumption that I can ignore the limit as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^{-}$ is correct.

Comment: could you say which function you're looking at?

Comment: By definition the limit only exists if the limits from both sides exist and are equal.

Comment: How does $f(x)$ depend on $\epsilon\,$?

Comment: @lappen68 I understand the definition of whether or not the limit exists. I'm not actually asked to take a formal limit here, but only to consider what happens when epsilon goes to zero. This is for an applied math class, not a calculus class, I've just never encountered a situation like this before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if $\varepsilon>0$ then it is enough to consider $\varepsilon\to0^+$.